# Add option to select2 dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I have read all possible references about how to add an option dynamically to select2, but none works. I guess those have been replicated.

The case is I want when user types in the searchbox of combo, I search through my list in server and show the matched ones in the list.

```
    <select class="js-data-example-ajax" id="mySelect2">
    </select>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
                language: "fa",
                dir: "rtl",
                ajax: {
                    url: 'search_employees',
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        for (i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++){
                            var newOption = new Option(data.items[i].name, data.items[i].id, false, false);
                            $('#mySelect2').append(newOption).trigger('change');
                        }
                    },
                    data: function (params) {
                        var query = {
                            search: params.term,
                            type: 'public'
                        };
                        // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&type=public
                        return query;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I'm sure about that 'search_employees' response, which is in this format:

```
{"items": [{"id": 8, "name": "Hamed"}]}
```

and '*data.items[i].name*' and '*data.items[i].id*' are correct.

I checked the code in inspect, there is some <*option*> tag for this code, I mean this is working and adding *Hamed* as an <*option*> tag inside this <*select*> but they are not shown at all.

Is there anything I am missing?

tnx

Comment: `$('#mySelect2')` and `$('.js-data-example-ajax')` looks different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply doing the following transformation in `processResults` handler?

```
 processResults: function (data) {
    if (data.items && data.items.length==0) {
        $('.js-data-example-ajax').val(null).trigger('change');
    }
    return {
        results: $.map(data.items, function(obj) {
          return { id: obj.id, text: obj.name };
    })
 };
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/htqyybmc/

*P.S.: in jsfiddle the ajax request is simulated, so the query is not applying and results are not filtered*

Comment: but there is a problem, if search returns null, the list doesn't omit the previous items in form or saying nothing found

Comment: you can add all your logic inside processResults, for example checking if zero items matching the query you can reset current value of select. I've updated my fiddle